# Variable Shadowing in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I get variable shadowing warnings in the following code for `it`, because it's nested. How do I fix this warning properly?

```
Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_one.php", dataToSend) {
    if (it["result"].toString() == "PASS")
    {
        Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_two.php", dataToSend) {
            if (it["result"].toString() == "PASS")
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Name your variables for the lambda `{x ->  // add code here}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code have some implicit hidden declarations `it -> ...`

```
Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_one.php", dataToSend) { it->
    if (it["result"].toString() == "PASS")
    {
        Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_two.php", dataToSend) { it->
            if (it["result"].toString() == "PASS")
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

just rename one or both of them:

```
Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_one.php", dataToSend) { it1->
    if (it1["result"].toString() == "PASS")
    {
        Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_two.php", dataToSend) { it2->
            if (it2["result"].toString() == "PASS")
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your inner lamda **it** to new one; like **item** or **data**

```
Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_one.php", dataToSend) { it->
    if (it["result"].toString() == "PASS")
    {
        Network.callServer(Constants.url + "/get_call_two.php", dataToSend) { item ->
            if (item["result"].toString() == "PASS")
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```